# Python Requests Complicated Post

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to use Requests to get to the "next" (right arrow) page of this URL:

https://www.sportstats.ca/display-results.xhtml?raceid=43572.

I used the chrome developer tools to examine the response when I do it manually in a browser and I've attempted to put together the form data and make a post with Requests, but the response I'm getting back still shows Page 1 in the content. Any tips? I've also tried using Selenium with mixed results, I'd much rather stick to lightweight Requests if at all possible. Here's my attempt:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.sportstats.ca/display-results.xhtml?raceid=43572'
with requests.Session() as s:
    r1 = s.get(url)
    pagenum = [x for x in r1.text.splitlines() if '<p>Page' in x][0].strip()
    print(pagenum)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r1.text, 'html.parser')
    hidden_inputs = soup.findAll('input', {'type': 'hidden'})
    prepayload = {x['name']: x['value'] for x in hidden_inputs}
    payload = {}
    payload['javax.faces.partial.ajax'] = 'true'
    payload['javax.faces.source'] = 'mainForm:j_idt386'
    payload['javax.faces.partial.execute'] = 'mainForm'
    payload['javax.faces.partial.render'] = 'mainForm:result_table mainForm:pageNav mainForm:eventAthleteDetailsDialog'
    payload['mainForm:j_idt386'] = 'mainForm:j_idt386'
    payload['mainForm'] = prepayload['mainForm']
    payload['mainForm:raceid'] = prepayload['mainForm:raceid']
    payload['mainForm:status'] = prepayload['mainForm:status']
    payload['mainForm:iframe'] = prepayload['mainForm:iframe']
    payload['mainForm:bib'] = ''
    payload['mainForm:lastname'] = ''
    payload['mainForm:city'] = ''
    payload['mainForm:firstname'] = ''
    payload['mainForm:province'] = ''
    payload['mainForm:categoryFilter'] = 'All Categories'
    payload['javax.faces.ViewState'] = prepayload['javax.faces.ViewState']
    r2 = s.post(url, data=payload)
    pagenum = [x for x in r2.text.splitlines() if '<p>Page' in x][0].strip()
    print(pagenum)
```

This comes back with:

```
[myname@myserver] $ ./sstest.py
<p>Page 1 / 19  
<p>Page 1 / 19
```

Answer (score 1):

The website you want to scrap is better suited for selenium.

All you need is to get the number of total number of pages from visiting the website, then you loop over the total number of pages and click on the next button once every loop.

During every loop you can do the required parsing for each page as you would normally do.

This way you have a script that dynamically parses each page according to the number of pages in the Website page.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

# Intializations
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://www.sportstats.ca/display-results.xhtml?raceid=43572'
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
bs = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

# Retrieve the total number of pages
PagesParser = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mainForm:pageNav"]/div/p')
pages = int(str(PagesParser.text).split('/')[1].replace(' ', ''))
print(pages)

# Loops over every page
for i in range(1, pages+1):
    print('page: ' + str(i))
    # Do your parsing here for every page
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mainForm:j_idt386"]').click() # Clicks the next button
```

Output:

```
19
page: 1
page: 2
page: 3
page: 4
page: 5
page: 6
page: 7
page: 8
page: 9
page: 10
page: 11
page: 12
page: 13
page: 14
page: 15
page: 16
page: 17
page: 18
page: 19
```